# The fonts that include the most symbols

Tags: fonts, typography, unicode

There are lots of resources on "the best" fonts for designers and such. But I would like to know of a list of fonts that have the most symbol coverage. For example, on my Mac I'm able to see most Chinese characters, Tibetan characters, Thai symbols, etc. Even ancient language symbols which no one uses. I'm not sure what font that is (which would be good to know); it has a lot of glyphs.

Wondering what a list of fonts with a lot of glyphs from unicode covered. Ideally they would be high quality.

For example, it seems the [GNU Unifont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Unifont) covers quite a bit of ground. I'm not sure about Helvetica, I'm not sure if there is Chinese and Thai versions of Helvetica, etc.

Basically would just like a list of 5 or 10 good ones, even some that may cover vast swaths of unicode would be good.

The obvious one is the new Google Noto font, but I can't think of any others.

Other inspiration, [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-largest-most-robust-Unicode-font) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14027/what-fonts-are-good-for-unicode-glyphs).

Comment: I don’t know about Macs, but I would expect that all modern operating systems use fallback fonts if a specific character is not available in the default font. Therefore what you see does not need to be from a single font to begin with and there is no big necessity that it is. In general there is no big point in having all writings systems covered by a single font.

Comment: I would just contact MyFonts or similar and ask them for their #1 or top 5 by character set size.